# Multithreading in python. Running the same program on multiple threads to make the program faster

Tags: python, python-multithreading

So I have a quite time-extensive python program and I was wondering, if (since my CPU is multi-core) I can run the program on multiple threads at once. I always check Task Manager and python uses only one thread but pushes it to the max.

I tried searching, but I only found ways to run a function with different datasets on different threads, so I didn't try anything yet, I hope you can help!

Comment: At least the standard implementation CPython uses the so-called "global interpreter lock" which makes multithreading useless in many cases. Look for multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Multithreading will use only one core due to GIL in Python. You might want to use multithreading or asyncio for multitask. This might help you https://medium.com/@kkarann07/multithreading-multiprocessing-and-asyncio-in-python-49a343f92ea4

Comment: It'll be very task specific. If you can divide your task in several smaller ones, you'll benefit from multithreading, but since you don't give details about the task we can't help you more...

Answer (score 0):

multi-threading won't help you.
But Python's "multiprocessing" might - however, parallelization is not automatic, and you have to adapt your program, knowing what you are doing, in order to have any gains with it.

Python's multi-threading is capped to only have a single thread running actual Python code at once - you ave some gains if parts of your workload are spent with I/O, but not with a CPU intensive task.

Multiprocessing is a module on Python's standard library which provide the same interface as `"threading" and will actually run your code in parallel, in multiple processes each one with its own Python runtime. Its major drawback is that any data exchanged between processes have to be serialized and de-serialized, and that add some overhead.

In either case, you have to write your program so that certain functions (which can be entry-points for big workloads) run in new threads or sub-processes. Since you have no example code, there is no example we could create for you showing how the code could be - but look for tutorials on "python multiprocessing" - those should help you out.